# How to fix Segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

Hello i wrote my c program which will be run on linux.
I am trying to make my own shell for linux.
I have the following code below...

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define MAX_LINE 80 /* 80 chars per line, per command, should be enough. */

int main(void){
       int i = 0;
       int k = 0;
       int argsCount = 0;
       char inputBuffer[MAX_LINE]; /*buffer to hold command entered */
       int background; /* equals 1 if a command is followed by '&' */
       char *args[MAX_LINE/2 + 1]; /*command line arguments */
       pid_t tpid ;
       pid_t child_pid;
       int child_status;
       char path[PATH_MAX+1];
       char *progpath = strdup(args[0]);
       char *prog = basename(progpath);
       char temp[MAX_LINE];
}
```

It'is compiling well but when i try to run the code it gives me segmentation fault error

How can i fix it and why i take this error?

Comment: Tried initializing `args[0]`(defining)?

Comment: `char *progpath = strdup(args[0]);` : `args[0]` is not initialize.

Comment: what is args[0] here

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use a debugger** (`gdb`) (and also [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `main` has a wrong signature. You want

```
 int main(int argsCount, char**args) {
```

and of course you should remove the *internal* declaration of `argCount` & `args` *inside* your `main`.

Perhaps you want instead your `args` & `argCount` to contain the parsed arguments of your own shell (but you still have to give a good signature to your `main`, conventionally and very often 
 `int main(int argc, char**argv)`.... you probably want your shell to accept the `-c` argument as most shells do, this would ease debugging with simplistic test cases). Then you should initialize them, and you should read some line (probably with [getline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)) in a loop.

As I commented, you should compile with all warnings & debug info:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g yoursource.c -o yourprog
```

Then use `gdb ./yourprog` to debug your program (see [GDB documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html)). [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) should also be helpful. Of course, be sure to develop on a Linux system!

BTW, your program is not a convincing start for a shell. Use `strace` on some *existing* shell to understand what a shell needs to do. Study the source code of some *existing* free software shell (e.g. [`sash`](http://members.tip.net.au/%7Edbell/programs/sash-3.8.tar.gz), [`fish`](http://fishshell.com/), [GNU `bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) ...). Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)